How to use a Meinberg reference clock in SLES15?
SUSE replaced ntpd with chrony in SLES15, and despite of the missing possibility of efficient remote monitoring (via "mode 6 " protocol), there seems to be a massive lack of reference clock drivers in chrony.
When I read the manual page, the only drivers are:

PPS
SHM
SOCK
PHC

As I understand it, these "devices" are all abstract ones that need an actual driver for the clock.
Up to SLES12 SP5 we could use ntpd to query our Meinberg PZF535 DFC-77 clock (no longer sold, but very excellent quality), but now we seem to be unable.
server 127.127.8.0 mode 0

So what can be done (other than complaining about SUSE's decision to drop ntpd)?

Which reference clock driver did you use with ntpd? https://www.ntp.org/documentation/4.2.8-series/refclock/

Looks like it might have been type 8 generic refclocks?  I think you're right there that chrony doesn't support it.  The usual process for that would be an external program that feeds the refclock signals into the SHM driver.  I'm in the Southern hemisphere, and we don't see DCF77 receivers down here, so I'm not sure if there are any such programs.

@PaulGear I added the config line to the question.

You should able to install and configure ntpd in SLES15. Just make sure to disable chrony.

@paladin Yes, that seems to be the best possible option, but I wonder why SUSE dropped ntpd support (replacing it with chrony) when enterprise customers are expected to use local reference clocks (the other advantage of ntpd is efficient remote monitoring that chrony also lacks so far)

@U.Windl SUSE states that chronyd is faster and more accurate in synchronizing from NTP servers. The only servers which should use a local reference clock are NTP servers and those are usually an appliance which probably still use ntpd.

Well, using local reference clocks may be rare, but we have one here that runs for more than 20 years (OK, they don't produce such quality any more).
